# При нажатии на кнопку выбираются чекбоксы

Tags: jquery, checkbox

> При нажатии на 1 кнопку должны выбраться 2 чекбокса (борт, борта) и к сумме добавляются значения, при нажатии на 2 кнопку выбирается только 2 чекбокс (борта). Не верно работает код:нажимаем 1 кнопку отмечаются чекбоксы верно, нажимаем 2 кнопку - выбирается 1 чекбокс вместо второго, после нажимаем обратно на 1 кнопку - выбирается только 1 чекбокс вместо двух.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //выбранный чекбокс добавляет к сумме:       
  $("#yslygi:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });
$("#yslygi2:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });
  //общая сумма
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}

  //выбрать чекбоксы
     $("#but1").click(function(){
    $("#yslygi").prop('checked', true);
    $("#yslygi2").prop('checked', true);});
    
     //выбрать чекбоксы  
    $("#but2").click(function(){
    $("#yslygi").prop('checked', false);
    $("#yslygi2").prop('checked', true);});
 
$('select,input').change(function() {
          calculate();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
  <option value="6300">Белава</option>
  <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option value="0">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="yslygi">Борт</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="bort" />100<br/>
Борта<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi2" name="bort2" />100<br/>
Стоимость <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="but1">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить2" id="but2">
```

Comment: вместо кликов лучше явно задавать _.prop('checked', true)_ или _.prop('checked', false)_. И не забывайте очищать checkBox-ы при нажатии кнопки

Comment: @exvayn Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @exvayn подскажите, пожалуиста, подсчет перестал работать.  $("#Bort:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });

Comment: не могу помочь без листинга кода. Обновите вопрос

Comment: @exvayn поправила

Comment: не вызываешь функцию _calculate()_ в конце событий _$("#but1").click_  и _$("#but2").click_. О стоп простите возможно не прав. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: получается prop не вызывает калбэк _change_ так что да надо calculate() в конце событий $("#but1").click и $("#but2").click добавить

Comment: @exvayn переставила,не работает

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли. Должен быть вызов внутри .click Пример прикрепил в ответе.

Comment: @exvayn Спасибо, теперь все считает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //выбранный чекбокс добавляет к сумме:       
  $("#yslygi:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });
  $("#yslygi2:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });
  //общая сумма
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}

//выбрать чекбоксы
$("#but1").click(function(){
  $("#yslygi").prop('checked', true);
  $("#yslygi2").prop('checked', true);
  calculate();
});

//выбрать чекбоксы  
$("#but2").click(function(){
  $("#yslygi").prop('checked', false);
  $("#yslygi2").prop('checked', true);
  calculate();
});

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
  <option value="6300">Белава</option>
  <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select><br/>

<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option value="0">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select><br/>

<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
</select><br/>

<label for="yslygi">Борт</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="bort" />100<br/>
Борта<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi2" name="bort2" />100<br/>
Стоимость <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.

<input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="but1">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить2" id="but2">
```